# reftesh another frame

Tags: php, html, sql

I make 1 page with 3 frame(frame 1 , frame 2 , frame 3)

```
frame 1 is for links
frame 2 is for inputs (insert update ... )
frame 3 is for search
```

in frame 2 than select insert button i want refresh frame 3 if result is true

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["insert"])){  
        $ColCode=$_POST["ColCode"];
        $colName=$_POST["colName"];
        $ColAccKind=$_POST["model"];
        $insert="INSERT INTO colacc (ColCode, colName, ColAccKind)
        VALUES ('$ColCode', '$colName', '$ColAccKind')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colName='$colName' , ColAccKind='$ColAccKind';";
        mysql_query($insert) or die ('error');
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfull');</script>";
        #refresh frame 3
    }?>
```

Comment: You have multiple SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code. You need to escape your inputs properly.

Comment: @user2588132 could you please undelete the question `form auto increase row and insert all row to mysql`..i've found a solution..was working on a fiddle..and please do inform me after undeleting the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that each of your frames has a 'name' tag.

```
<frame name="framename" src="frame.html">
```

Then you can use Javascript to reload that frame.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>parent.framename.location.reload();</script>
```